# Export navigationOptions as a component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible and how to export and import navigationOptions as a component

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  headerLeft: (<Text />),
  title: (
    <Image style={{width: 500, height: 125}} source={require("../images/logo_orfo.png")} />
  ),
};
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be a React component since the function doesn't return any JSX or React.createElement instances. However, you can use it as a module like this:

NavComponent.js

```
//imports here

export default ({ navigation }) => {
 return {
  headerLeft: (<Text />),
  title: (
    <Image style={{width: 500, height: 125}} source=
 {require("../images/logo_orfo.png")} />
  ),
 }; 
};
```

then import like this

```
import NavComponent from './NavComponent';
...
static navigationOptions = NavComponent
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very useful !!